# I am from the future, and I need your help to meet someone

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

I came from the future. Earlier today (when I was still in the future), I was supposed to meet my friend. I asked

> Where do we meet today?

The response was

> I feel depressed lately, I need some fresh air.
>
> Maybe Bournemouth would be a good place to come back to life.
>   If you catch me in Dublin, remember your wife.
>
> I will spread my wings to Rhode Island some time.
>   But you should meet me in Ketchum, hear the chime?

I asked

> Are you kidding me? We're in Europe and you're telling me places from the United States!

he answered

> No, this is not a joke. I would have been joking if we were to meet earlier.

I could not figure out where to meet my friend. At the end of the day, he was very tired and told me that we must have met, I missed it.

I think I missed his clues. So, I came back in time to ask you, guys. Where were we supposed to meet?

**Hint:**

> He always tells me that I should read more books to understand complicated sentences of his.

Oh, almost forgot.
Here is one from me:

> From what day did I come?

**Hint 2:**

> He told that we should've met, and *I missed it*.

**Hint 3:**

> By earlier, I think he meant the day before.

**Hint 4:**

> "Dublin is different than the others. It is where a story started. The other places are the ends of different stories."

**Hint 5:**

> Except Dublin, the rest are very peaceful places. Some people rest in those places.

**Hint 6:**

> Turns out he said "you missed it, you missed *the whole show*."

**Ultimate hints:**

> Each place except Dublin is where a famous author's grave is. However, the puzzle has nothing to do with the authors, but it's related to the works of the authors. As in [Gareth McCaughan's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/57398/), two of the books are Frankenstein, and For Whom the Bell Tolls. He found H. P. Lovecraft too, but failed to realize in which book of his there is a **winged crature**.

About Dublin,

> It is the birthplace of a not-so-famous author [Sarah Crossan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Crossan). She also has a novel which is related to the other ones.

Also, please consider that in the comments I wrote

> What is Frankenstein? As in "what is Jabberwock?" or "what is a gremlin?" You answer it by using some specific <s>preposition</s> adjective. Which one? Try explaining "mom/dad, what is a raccoon?" to a 3-year-old boy. "Raccoon is .... animal darling."

Way later edit and final hint:

> I missed it, guys. It was April 1st in O2 Stadium at Prague.

## Full answer

After many months I reveal the full answer.
Here is what my friend meant:

I feel depressed lately, I need some fresh air.

> An outdoor place.

Maybe Bournemouth would be a good place to come back to life.

> This refers to the birthplace of [Mary Shelley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/57398/), the author of the book [Frankenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Crossan). The book is about **some kind of monster**.

If you catch me in Dublin, remember your wife.

> This is the birthplace of [Sarah Crossan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Crossan), of whose most famous book is [One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(Crossan_novel))

I will spread my wings to Rhode Island some time.

> This is the place where the famous author [H. P. Lovecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft) was born (and also died). On of the most famous books of him is [The Call of Cthulhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Call_of_Cthulhu)

But you should meet me in Ketchum, hear the chime?

> [Ernest Hemingway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Hemingway) was died in Ketchum, and one of his most famous books is [For Whom the Bell Tolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Whom_the_Bell_Tolls).

Now, if you consider the book titles,

> Some Kind of Monster, One, The Call of Ktulu, For Whom the Bell Tolls, all of them are Metallica songs. The event we should've meet at was the Metallica concert in April 1st in O2 arena.

Also,

> I am aware that Frankenstein is the doctor in the book, but the song was originally called Frankenstein (fun fact!).

Comment: Is it important to figure out who this person is (assuming it is an actual person)?

Comment: @Lazer no, he is just an ordinary person.

Comment: @padawan, Than I will stop trying to make a connection with your puzzle and Oscar Wilde.

Comment: @Lazer You are onto something. But the puzzle is not about who my friend is. He's describing some place.

Comment: Lovecraft's story is "The gable window", no?

Comment: @M.Dm. So far as I can tell, that's by Derleth not by Lovecraft. Do wings feature importantly in it?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan There is a book of Lovecraft, in which there exists a winged *thing*.

Comment: Nice to find out the answer at last! Though I'm not sure I really deserve that green checkmark you kindly gave me :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You solved all the clues wihtout any mistakes, and even more! I believe you couldn't conclude because you're either not familiar with the band or the songs. I wouldn't dare not to accept such an answer :)

Comment: Indeed I'm not familiar with the band or the songs. I mean, of course I've _heard of_ Metallica, everyone has, but if I've ever heard any of their music then I don't remember doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Extremely partial answer**

I think I know at least part of the shape of what we're looking for.

```
Maybe Bournemouth would be a good place to come back to life.
```

> Mary Shelley wrote *Frankenstein* ("come back to life"), lived near Bournemouth at the end of her life, and was buried there.

```
 But you should meet me in Ketchum, hear the chime?
```

> Ernest Hemingway wrote *For Whom the Bell Tolls* ("hear the chime") and spent his last couple of years living in Ketchum.

So I guess we're looking for [NOTE: I've edited the following in the light of recent hints from OP, but I'm still as confused as before :-).]

> someone *born* in Dublin one of whose works matches "remember your wife", and someone who *died* or *was buried* in Rhode Island one of whose works (more specifically, probably *books*) matches "spread my wings"; apparently these are Sarah Crossan and H P Lovecraft. But which works? I've looked at descriptions of (so far as I can tell) all Sarah Crossan's books, and for none of them can I see anything in either the title or the plot that corresponds to "remember your wife". As for H P Lovecraft, his most famous creation is probably Cthulhu, who has wings but doesn't have a whole book to himself; according to Some Random Pages On The Internet, there are also the Elder Things (found in *At the Mountains of Madness*) and the Night-Gaunts (found in *The Dream-Quest of Unknown Kadath*). Neither of those novellas was a book in Lovecraft's lifetime (the former was published serially, the latter posthumously) and neither (I think) is now a book on its own, but I think for both there are now books containing that as title story together with a few other short pieces. Other answers here mention *Winged Death* which must be a strong candidate, and *The Music of Erich Zann* in which I can find no wings at all. None of this is helping me much right now.

And then

> we need to combine Shelley/Frankenstein, Crossan/?, Lovecraft/?, and Hemingway/FWTBT somehow to get what we're after. (The name of a famous theatre or something of the kind, perhaps, given "You missed the whole show"?)

OP invites us to ask

> "what is Frankenstein?" and to pay attention to adjectives. I'm afraid I find this unenlightening; it seems like there are an awful lot of adjectives one could reasonably use to describe (as OP's hint suggests that "Frankenstein" here means) the monster, and no one of them seems uniquely inevitable. ("Lonely", "violent", "scary", "artificial", ...)

Some other thoughts that so far haven't led anywhere useful:

> This business about coming *from the future* is obviously significant. Presumably some future day on which there is a "whole show" to miss. (And, per hint 4, there wasn't on the previous day.) Christmas? New Year? Opening night of some movie or musical or something? OP has been at pains to tell us that it's specifically in Europe, which seems like it might be informative. But the future and Europe are both large :-). Hint 5 suggests that we might be looking specifically for the *graves* of our deceased authors, but it doesn't seem as if there's anything terribly interesting about those of Hemingway and Shelley. And then there's the bit about depression and fresh air; perhaps that just indicates that the place we're looking for is in the open?

I wondered

> whether perhaps there's some common plot theme, or character name, or something, between the works we're looking at. I guess both *Frankenstein* and *For Whom the Bell Tolls* have something to do with death and violence; there's a fair bit of death and violence in Lovecraft, but not so much in Crossan (though her latest, *Moonrise*, features someone convicted of murder and condemned to execution -- but it seems sadly lacking in recollected wives). Beyond that, nothing springs out at me. I notice also that the two books I've definitely identified have titles beginning with F, but none of Crossan's seems to :-).

Much the most plausible common theme seems to me to be

> death. We have the places of death of three of our authors; perhaps the adjective OP has in mind for Frankenstein is "undead" (which I think is appropriate for the movies but not so much for the book); perhaps the Lovecraft work is *Winged Death*; the tolling bell in Donne (and hence Hemingway) is a funeral one; if indeed the Crossan we're after is *Moonrise* then one of its central characters is both killer and killed.

If so, then perhaps the intended meeting date was

> Hallowe'en, traditionally associated with death and graveyards and so forth. The following day, All Hallows' Day, is rather the reverse. Perhaps the "whole show" is a witches' sabbath or something of the sort. But, while this all seems nicely thematic and evocative, it also seems rather loose; I can't help feeling there must be something more specific going on with those particular authors and works. And we haven't identified a specific place to meet, though the above suggests it might end up being a graveyard.

I suspect, as the reader will gather, that the last two spoiler blocks are basically twaddle, but they're the best I have for now.

Comment: You are very, very close! I'm truly impressed.

Comment: A hint: *What* is Frankenstein?

Comment: Well, *Frankenstein* (the book) is a novel; Frankenstein (the character in the book) is a scientist; Frankenstein (the creature frequently though wrongly so called) is a hideous but misunderstood undead creature. It's also the title of a movie. The book has a subtitle alluding to an earlier legend (and *For Whom the Bell Tolls* has a title quoting from an earlier work). None of that is giving anything away to me just yet, but I'll think some more...

Comment: You're on the right track in terms of following the clues, but I suppose they are bringing you to somewhere else. By *what* is Frankenstein, I meant the definiton. As in the dictionary. It is .....

Comment: (I've removed a couple of my comments that might give to much away to people not wanting to read spoilers, and instead put essentially the same comments into my answer. They were not directly relevant to padawan's hinty question.)

Comment: Please excuse my dimness, but I'm not sure how to answer the reiterated question. It's ... a novel? a monster? a noun? a name? an eponym? (OED sez: "Commonly misused allusively as a typical name for a monster who is a terror to his originator and ends by destroying him.")

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Isn't Frankenstein the scientist?

Comment: In the novel, the scientist is called Victor Frankenstein and the monster is not named. In subsequent popular usage, the monster is commonly called Frankenstein. (Hence "Commonly misused allusively" in the OED definition.)

Comment: Definition of "Frankenstein" as per OED "1. A character in the novel Frankenstein, or the Modern Prometheus (1818) by Mary Shelley. Frankenstein is a scientist who creates and brings to life a manlike monster which eventually turns on him and destroys him; Frankenstein is not the name of the monster itself, as is often assumed.
1.1 [as noun] A thing that becomes terrifying or destructive to its maker." My guess is the 1.1 definition is the hint?

Comment: Could very well be. (Incidentally, although that's a definition from an OUP website it's not in fact from the OED.)

Comment: When I saw this bumped into the homepage I thought it's finally solved. Grrr!!!

Comment: Sorry! Still as confused by it as ever :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Well, Frankenstein is obviously the surname of the scientist, and not his monster. This is unfortunately a slippery slope, since I had to use the popular misuse of it. That is because slightly related to the puzzle. Oh gosh it is so hard to give hints without giving away the answer! LOL

Comment: "Frankenstein": free stones.

Answer (score 2):

2017-12-08: Since nobody got any further, I'll post some ideas I came up with.

Lazer's guess gave me a hunch to look for
>! eclipses. I have no idea why Lazer guessed sun-related events, but assuming there was a reason, an eclipse would fit the idea of travelling, being tired at the end of the day and at least a bit the theme of resurrection/reanimation.

and your hinting on a specific day, and mentioning that he would have been joking, had the appointment been a day earlier, gave me the hunch that this day might be
>! the 1st of April, thinking of April's Fools jokes. Which would make the appointed day the 2nd of April.

combining this, I looked for
>! eclipses on the 2nd of April. The only I could find will be 2117. But as I could not find any hint in the riddle that would make the exact 100 years offset click, and this specific eclipse would mainly be visible over the ocean near Australia, which would certainly fit being tired, but I can't detect any connection to the other four places.

As for your hint/question "What IS Frankenstein":
>! It's a novel. May substitute tale, fiction, story, literature or narrative. If you want to be a bit unprecise, you could also say it's a book.

And another thing. I'm getting confused with your wording. Sorry, I would have posted this as comment but lack the reputation to do so.

1. just to be clear: Since you very clearly state you already met your friend after you were supposed to meet and came back in time, I assume we talk about actual time-travel (in this hypothetical setting of the riddle) and not some date-line trickery. Do I assume correctly?
2. I assume the following sequence of events from my perspective and point in time:

1. point in time (what I would call now): you talk to me about the riddle
2. point in time: You are/were supposed to meet your friend
3. point in time: You will talk/have talked your friend after missing the actual appointment and he seems very tired and tells you that you "missed it"
4. point in time: You traveled back to 1. point in time.
   Going by your wording of "At the end of the day, he was very tired and told me..." I further assume that 2 and 3 are on the same day.
   Is that right?

3.) assuming 2. is right enough to let this still make sense: you say "Earlier today (when I was still in the future)"

Does that mean all points in time laid out in 2. are all on the same day.

Or did you just add the explanation to explain that you were supposed to meet earlier that day you come from, so points 2, 3 and 4 are on the same day but not necessarily 1, which might be a lot earlier?

Or does the today refer to the day that I call today but your appointment is still in my future, so the main point is that points 1, 2 and 3 are on the same day, but not necessarily 4.

Or is this all of nor real relevance? Or is the answer to this too much part of the puzzle?

4.) In the original text your friend said that you MUST have met, but in your hints you word it SHOULD've met. Big difference to me. Does it matter or can I go with "should"?

Thanks

---

EDIT 2017-12-08: Oh, new hints just arrived ;-)

Commenting on your ultimate hints:

> I can only find "Winged Death" with a direct relation to wings. If you are hinting towards a story with a winged creature in it (just in the story, not in the title) then we have an abundance of titles to check, as winged creatures or winged avatars are quite common in the Mythos. Might even be the rather famous Call of Cthulhu, since Great Cthulhu also has wings, although this is definitely not its most prominent quality and no-one who witnesses his presence cares whether he spreads them or not.

(edit 2017-12-15, because Gareth is right and my memory faulty:)

> I just read the story again and there is no winged creature in The Music of Erich Zann. I have no idea from which depths of insanity my mind sprung that up.

Commenting on ultimate hint "Dublin":
>! Thanks, I needed that hint, wouldn't have found her on my own. Still at a loss about the particular title this is about. Breathe would fit to needing some fresh air, but I can't find something about wife or bride or similar.

Commenting on ultimate hint "hint from your comments"
>! I don't find myself in need of a preposition to answer that. Did you by chance mean adjective or prefix, or really preposition? Also, did we agree that Frankenstein is synonymous for Frankenstein's monster? In that case, a might add creature, fictional, monster or one of horrible, horrifying, horrific, ect to the list that maybe enlightens one of my fellow solvers.

I'll keep thinking about it.

---

EDIT 2017-12-13, more thoughts:

I am still wondering why the text explicitly states to meet your friend in Ketchum, and then asks where to meet them. So I assume the line about Ketchum codes the hint for the exact location. But if so, you would probably not be able to catch your friend in Dublin, so why phrase it like that? Anyone has an idea on this?

Might have a new lead on Dublin here:

> If "remember your wife" is a hint to the story, and it's not meant to be obvious from the title but relates to the content (as for instance with Frankenstein), then I'd suggest "We Come Apart" as the title of choice here. As far as I managed to skim the summaries, it's the only book clearly about the topic of marriage and wives.

And here is another approach I cancelled, but would like to mention in case it's not so bad as I think:

> The overall theme of returning from the dead gave me the idea to check for christian Easter ceremonies. Would also fit meeting at the toll of a bell (no match for Dublin though). Also I was looking for a public, open air ceremony, since the friend needs some fresh air. My current fixation on 2nd of April though doesn't add up, as resurrection day will be Sunday 1st of April 2018.

As for why I am fixated to look for a certain date at the moment:
>! The date comes from the hint that the friend would have been joking if they were to meet one day earlier, and for the time being I can only think of April 1st as an answer to that hint, so if that's right, the meeting was (or will be) scheduled on a 2nd of April. With nothing else to go by, it would be reasonable to assume the year is the next one, which is 2018.

And just for fun:

> There is a group in Germany that does Horror Diners. They had Dr. Frankenstein, trying to create yet another monster (nice match on Bournemouth, one show was in actual castle Falkenstein btw), Dracula, looking for a new bride (nice match on Dublin, although contradicting OP's hint about the author there), and of course each diner starts at the chime of a bell (meet me at...). No real match for Rhode Island, though, but this one just has too many winged creatures in his stories to be sure about that anyway.
>  
>  Apart from suspecting OP wouldn't know the guys nor make up a riddle for such a small event, the present show is Jack the Ripper and none will take place on 2nd of April. So no match, but for a few minutes after I started reading their Web site it really looked good :-)

---

EDIT 2017-12-14. (deleted due to Gareth's note that it was a false lead)

Comment: Wow, great approach! Your bullet #2 is correct all the way. I'm telling the story NOW. But when I was in future say day x, my friend told the sentence "if we have met on day y < x."

As for must-should, it is a mistake by me. I honestly mix em al all the time. I think it is "should" because I missed the meeting.

Comment: Hmm - you're *also* from the future? 2018? :O

Comment: You are so close! Think about the titles of the novels.

Comment: @Mithrandir - Well spotted. The timeline is now corrected.

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick I think that's a different Sarah Crossan. At any rate, the theologian John Crossan is married to someone called Sarah who shows no sign of being in any way related to our Irish author.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan - well spotted as well. On a closer look, that certainly looks like the wrong Sarah. I should have had and taken more time to double check. Sorry for the false lead. - I hope nobody minds if I just remove it from my post.

Comment: It is an event, and yes, it is an public event. But not a ceremony. It is some show. Live show. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

I have no support or explanation for my answer but I would like to guess:

> Sunrise?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Where we meet is a place.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand the thoughts of Gareth McCaughan.

Taking your suggestions for Bournemouth and Ketchum as a hit for now, and the overall morbid theme

Dublin might refer to

> Bram Stoker and Dracula. - I don't see what that's to do with the wife right now, but it might fit the theme.

Regarding Rhode Island, the place referred to might be the

> Swan Point Cemetery, which has the connection to wings in it's name, although I'd expect a work of the author to relate to that, not the cemetery.

also your last suggestion

> H.P. Lovecraft

would fit "wings" with the title

> Winged death

Or fitting the theme of my other guesses:

> Herbert West - Reanimator, which would at least fit the theme set by Frankenstein's monster and Dracula (if my other guess is right).
>  (edited 2017-12-15 after discovering that my memory of the suggested story was wrong)

Nothing of this is a strong hit, but maybe it helps someone to get on.

Comment: Your suggestion is partially correct, but unfortunately that part is not related to the rest of the inferences.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this should be a comment on a more complete answer, however I have not yet the reputation for it -

> In regards to Lovecraft's Winger Creature, his short story "The Hound" appears to be based on the eponymous Hound Amulet, a small statuette of a winged hound.
>
>  If this is the correct story, we have:
>  Shelley - Frankenstein
>  Crossan- N/A
>  Lovecraft - The Hound
>  Hemingway - For Whom the Bell Tolls.
>
>  Assuming Crossans book to be Apple and Rain. Containing a character named Apple, along with the hints about Frankenstein and The Jabberwock (a poem in Alice's Adventures), perhaps Eponymous, or Titular, could be on track?

Comment: Since you can comment on your own entries: What's your reasoning behind your Dublin assumption? I can't find any correlations to "wife" except for in WCA.

Comment: I admit that it's shoe horning a bit, but Apple's Mother, I'm assuming would have been married at some point (I haven't been able to get a copy of the book to flick through). Leaving Apple with only memories of her Mother. Wife being used to fit the rhyming scheme while still making sense? In short, I was looking for one of her (few) books, in which a woman is "lost".

Comment: You may also be right about the Rhode Island one, but again: is there any specific clue why you prefer this of all the others? This Rhode Islander is abound with winged creatures. There are quite some potential candidates for wings, and also some of the living entities are called "things", so OP's hint does not necessarily relate to an inanimate object. - Any detail that helps nailing this down would be very welcome..

Comment: OK, I get that. Thanks. Given that they look all rather vague to me, I agree that could be a hit.

Comment: I went with that particular one for Rhode Island as I have read all of the Authors work, but none particularly focused on the Winged aspect of the creatures. On the hint to look at the titles, the Winged Object/Creature is directly referenced in the title, and Winged is almost the only description given to the object.

Comment: I have to admit that I am not intimately familiar with the author's work, rather glancingly. If you are certain that the rest of the stories do not so directly address the winged aspect, that really helps to narrow it down. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Well, though not an answer, it may act as a lead, perhaps

> As the narrated story is about a person arriving from *future*, the GMT and locations on either side of it play a role here.

Assume that the author (of this puzzle)

> has started from an European city (where already date is advanced) which is considerably ahead of time  and reached **Dublin** before a date change has happened locally (justifying the statement - coming from future).

Also

> as the meeting could not take place, the meeting place must have been far from the GMT, towards west, for which  only Dublin suits, as compared to Bournemouth/Ketchum/Rhode Island(all these are not actual places...but sort of famous restaurants/coffee shops).

Hence the meeting place is

> Dublin

Comment: Good one! But not that. What did my friend mean when he said "you missed it"?